# Email sending stopped working on Siteground Cloud server

Tags: wordpress, email, plugins, amazon-ses

The Offload SES Lite plugin is super cool and it was working perfectly when my website is hosted with **WP-Engine** server. Now I moved my website to **Siteground Cloud server** and it stopped working. However, when I deactivated the plugin then again the email starts working but then  it is delivering in spam/junk folder.

My DKIM and all TXT records are showing as verified on my Amazon AWS Console

[image]

**Verification Status**: verified
**DKIM Status**: verified
**Enabled for Sending**: Yes

This is the error message keep getting when I send test email from plugin's page:

```
Error executing "SendRawEmail" on "https://email.us-east-1.amazonaws.com"; AWS HTTP error: Client error: `POST https://email.us-east-1.amazonaws.com` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response: <ErrorResponse xmlns="http://ses.amazonaws.com/doc/2010-12-01/"> 

<Error> <Type>Sender</Type> 

<Code>MessageReje (truncated...) MessageRejected (client): Sending paused for this account. For more information, please check the inbox of the email address associated with your AWS account. - <ErrorResponse xmlns="http://ses.amazonaws.com/doc/2010-12-01/"> 

<Error> <Type>Sender</Type> 
<Code>MessageRejected</Code> 
<Message>Sending paused for this account. For more information, please check the inbox of the email address associated with your AWS account.</Message> 
</Error> 

<RequestId>207abefe-4ed7-4013-9c11-4aa1f47c0f04</RequestId> 

</ErrorResponse>
```

Please suggest what causing issue as this was working on previous server but stopped when we moved to new cloud server on siteground.

I also contacted the Siteground team and they are saying that the issue is from applications end but its not.

Thanks.

Comment: The error says `400 Bad Request`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/400  . The 400 Bad Request Error is something that has to do with the client's submitted request before it is even processed by the server. So yes, siteground team might be right saying that it is a problem with the application, not the server. maybe try to deinstall the plugin and setting up everything again?

Comment: I did this but after reactivating the plugin does not seems to be working. I have a strong feeling that server team needs to guide us in order to get the email working. It is perfectly working on wpengine server

Comment: Or it could be a problem with the configuration. Did you try to install in the plugin in a "fresh" wordpress site and test if it is working with complete new installation of every component? Just to make sure, it is not a problem of the "moving" of the system.

Comment: I saw the amazon ses console and the account is under review because the current bounce rate is 15.01%. They measured this rate over the last 8,547 eligible emails* we sent for the last 205.1 days. Don't know how this going to be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

SiteGround VPS's by default often set the 'envelope-from' email header when left to their own devices, and they will set it to something that is not the same as the declaired 'From' email header you've defined.  It will likely be fdo0gbo8mjhs@c54292.sgvps.net or something similar.

This will instantly make DKIM fail.

For any such DKIM rejection errors, you need to actively set the envelope-from value in your code.